# Basis for $\operatorname{null}T$ given basis for $\operatorname{range}T$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to solve exercise 24 of chapter 3.B of "Linear Algebra done right", by Sheldon Axler. It states:

> Suppose $W$ is finite-dimensional and $T_1, T_2 \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$. Prove that $\operatorname{null} T_1 \subset \operatorname{null} T_2$ if and only if there exists $S \in \mathcal{L}(W,W)$ such that $T_2 = ST_1$.

I found a "solution" to this exercise at https://linearalgebras.com/3b.html. It starts by proving one direction of the implication and states at the beginning: "Suppose $\operatorname{null} T_1 \subset \operatorname{null}T_2$. [...] Let $Tv_1, \cdots, Tv_n$ be a basis for $\operatorname{range}T$, then the list $v_1, \cdots, v_n$ is linearly independent. Let $K = \operatorname{span}(v_1, \cdots,v_m) $, then $V = K \oplus \operatorname{null} T$."

I think the last result can be showed like this: given the list $n_1, \cdots, n_k$ is a basis for $\operatorname{null} T$, then we can extend this list to a basis $n_1, \cdots, n_k, v_1, \cdots, v_n$. Since the list $v_1, \cdots, v_n$ is linearly independent and each $v_i$ is linearly independent from all $n_i$ (otherwise $T(v_i) = 0$), by the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim V = k + n$, so $n_1,\cdots, n_k, v_1, \cdots, v_n$ indeed forms a basis of $V$ and $V = K \oplus \operatorname{null} T$. Is this reasoning correct?

I also wanted to consider a similar statement. Let $Tv_1, \cdots, Tv_n$ be a basis for $\operatorname{range}T$, if we extend $v_1, \cdots, v_n$ to a basis $v_1, \cdots, v_n, v_{n+1},\cdots, v_m$ of  $V$ then the list $v_{n+1},\cdots, v_m$ is a basis for $\operatorname{null} T$. This would mean that if $V = K \oplus G$ then $G = \operatorname{null} T$. Is this statement true?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Why do you want to prove this?  You will have some difficulty since it is not true.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have added context and reformulated the question. Is it acceptable now?

Comment: Very good! @Joca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^{3} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{4}$ be a linear transformation such that:

1) $T(1,0,0) = (1,0,0,0)$ and $T(0,1,0) = (0, 1, 0, 0)$

Let $ A = \lbrace T(1,0,0), T(0,1,0) \rbrace \subset \mathbb{R}^{4}$ be a base for $\text{Range}(T)$.

2) $B =\lbrace (1,0,0), (0,1,0) \rbrace \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ is linearly independent.

Completing $B$ to a base of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, for example : $B_{1} = \lbrace (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1) \rbrace$

we can do it : $T(0,0,1) = (1,1,0,0)$ and this case $T(0,0,1) \not \in Null(T)$.

Therefore $\lbrace (1,0,0) \rbrace$ is not a base for $\text{Null}(T)$.

Comment: But then, $T(1, 0, 0), T(0, 1, 0)$ cannot be a base for $range \ T$ since $T(0,0,1) \in range T$ but $T(0,0,1) \notin span(T(1,0,0), T(0,1,0))$

Comment: @Joca. You are right. I edited my answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's right, thank you! I was trying to hard to prove it was true and didn't consider counter examples.

Comment: @Joca. Normal. Sometimes we forget to even think about counterexamples. Success !!